# Puzzling Advent Calendar - 2021

Tags: discussion

December is just around the corner, and besides the upcoming [Winter Bash](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com), you'll have something else to look forward to on Puzzling.SE:

A christmas-themed puzzle every day between the 1st and 24th of December, where the best answer will be rewarded with a bounty. The bounties are calculated as follows:

- For the question posted on christmas eve, the bounty will be worth 200 reputation
- For questions posted on sundays, the bounty will be worth 100 reputation
- On all other days, the bounty will be worth 50 reputation.

---

To make this work, we need a few users who are willing to prepare nice puzzles for this event. Note that the awarding of bounties is solely my responsibility, not that of the puzzle setter. You should meet the following criteria:

- You have posted at least one question on PSE with a vote score that's at least 5
- The puzzle is christmas-themed ([seasonal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasonal))
- The title of the puzzle should be `PSE Advent Calendar 2021 (Day X): {puzzle title}`
- A header with a link to this post and the previous/next entries of the calendar (if and when available): `<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling StackExchange Advent Calendar 2021](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/37714). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth {X} reputation.<br><br>[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](link) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](link)</sub><hr>`
- If possible, please post a hint every ~24 hours as long as your puzzle remains unsolved.

Please do not announce your participation in an answer or comment to this post. We will plan the allocations of puzzles in a spreadsheet and coordinate / discuss puzzles in [this dedicated chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131587/pse-advent-calendar).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below is a list of [all puzzles posted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3APSE+Advent+Calendar+2021) as part of the Puzzling Advent Calendar 2021:

1. [La laa laaaaaa laa la Christmas](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112854) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)
2. [A Christmas Tree for broke Nerds](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112869) by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37714)
3. [Tentai Show](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112877) by [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973)
4. [Decorating with Ingrid Deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112909) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
5. [Christmas Shopping](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112921) by [Lypyrhythm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/47620)
6. [Naughty or Nice?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112939) by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37714)
7. [Don't forget the lyrics!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112952) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)
8. [Reindeer Family Reunion](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112982) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
9. [Christmas songs in emoji](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112995) by [sarsaparilla](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60396)
10. [The distracted gridsmith](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/113011/pse-advent-calendar-2021-day-10-the-distracted-gridsmith) by [Jafe](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41973)
11. [What Child – Er, Game Is This?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/113023) by [Sciborg](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/53621)
12. [Christmas Confusion](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/113039) by [LOTGP](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/62170/lotgp)
13. [A Christmas Hokuro](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/113040) by [sarsaparilla](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60396/sarsaparilla)
14. [An international reunion](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/113053/pse-advent-calendar-2021-day-14-an-international-reunion) by [Jafe](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41973)
15. [Optics Experiment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/113091/pse-advent-calendar-2021-day-15-optics-experiment) by 
    [hb20007](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25396)
16. [Poké(snow)ball battle!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/114106/60644) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)
17. [That's the way the cookie crumbles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114119) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217/jeremy-dover)
18. [A Reunion, and Christmas Decorations](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114128) by [Jerry Dean](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/75367/jerry-dean)
19. [Santa's Dilemma](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114132/pse-advent-calendar-2021-day-19-santas-dilemma) by [Stevo](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/73193/stevo?tab=summary)
20. [Candy Cane Sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114146/pse-advent-calendar-2021-day-20-candy-cane-sudoku) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217/jeremy-dover)
21. [How the Grinch Trolled Quizmas](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114155/pse-advent-calendar-2021-day-21-how-the-grinch-trolled-quizmas) by [TwoBitOperation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29430)
22. [Quick Math Card](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114160) by [cap](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57156)
23. [Gee, I Really Wonder Where We'll Land](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114175/pse-advent-calendar-2021-day-23-gee-i-really-wonder-where-well-land) by [samm82](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50054/samm82)
24. [The Witneys - Your Comfy Puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/114197/28719) by [athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28719/athin)

---

<sub>At the end of the event, statistics will be posted here, such as the top users who were rewarded the most bounty points.</sub>