# Puzzling Advent Calendar - 2022

Tags: discussion

We will continue this [tradition](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7272/puzzling-advent-calendar-2021) from last year: A Christmas-themed puzzle every day between the 1st and 24th of December, where the accepted answer will be rewarded with a bounty. The bounties are calculated as follows:

- For the question posted on Christmas eve, the bounty will be worth 200 reputation.
- For questions posted on Sundays, the bounty will be worth 100 reputation.
- On all other days, the bounty will be worth 50 reputation.

---

To make this work, we need a few users who are willing to prepare nice puzzles for this event. Note that the awarding of bounties is solely my responsibility, not that of the puzzle setter. To post a puzzle for this event, you should meet the following criteria:

- You have posted at least one question on PSE with a vote score of at least 5.
- The puzzle is Christmas-themed ([seasonal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasonal)).
- The title of the puzzle should be `PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day X): {puzzle title}`.
- A header with a link to this post and the previous/next entries of the calendar (if and when available): `<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2022](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7414/37714). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth {X} reputation.<br><br>[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](link) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](link)</sub><hr>`
- If possible, please post a hint every ~24 hours as long as your puzzle remains unsolved.

Please do not announce your participation in an answer or comment to this post. We will plan the allocations of puzzles in a spreadsheet and coordinate / discuss puzzles in [this dedicated chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140093/pse-advent-calendar-2022).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List of [all posted puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3APSE+Advent+Calendar+2022) as part of the PSE Advent Calendar 2022

1. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 1): A festive Sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118883/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-1-a-festive-sudoku) by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37714/lukas-rotter)
2. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 2): Santa’s Magic Knapsack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118893/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-2-santa-s-magic-knapsack) by [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe)
3. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 3): Okay everybody, from the top!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118907/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-3-okay-everybody-from-the-top) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv)
4. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 4): Letters to Father Christmas (Sgt. Sequence Fan-Fic)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118918/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-4-letters-to-father-christmas-sgt-sequence-fan) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217/jeremy-dover)
5. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 5): The Double Slitherlink Experiment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118929/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-5-the-double-slitherlink-experiment) by [sarsaparilla](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60396/sarsaparilla)
6. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 6): Christmas and Squares](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118938/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-6-christmas-and-squares) by [Anonymus 25](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/72797/anonymus-25)
7. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 7): Christmas Settings](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118949/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-7-christmas-settings) by [ACB](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/81979/acb)
8. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 8): Dash away! Dash away! Dash away all!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118955/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-8-dash-away-dash-away-dash-away-all) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv)
9. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 9): International Christmas Crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118971/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-9-international-christmas-crossword) by [hb20007](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25396/hb20007)
10. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 10): A Cryptmas Carol](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118975/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-10-a-cryptmas-carol) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217/jeremy-dover)
11. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 11): The other side of Christmas](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118984/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-11-the-other-side-of-christmas) by [Retudin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71170/retudin)
12. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 12): Pair up!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-12-pair-up) by [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe)
13. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 13): Sweden’s Sankta Lucia](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119008/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-13-sweden-s-sankta-lucia) by [parz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/79541/parz)
14. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 14): Let's decorate the tree!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119014/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-14-lets-decorate-the-tree) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv)
15. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 15): Candy Cane Crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119022/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-15-candy-cane-crossword) by [TakingNotes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54081/takingnotes)
16. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 16): A Christmas Card from my Travel Agent](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119034/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-16-a-christmas-card-from-my-travel-agent) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217/jeremy-dover)
17. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 17) Priority polar problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119045/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-17-priority-polar-problem) by [Retudin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71170/retudin)
18. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 18): Light Up the Christmas Tree](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119060/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-18-light-up-the-christmas-tree) by [juicifer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/77182/juicifer)
19. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 19): At the Theater](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119069/) by [msh210](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/93/msh210)
20. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 20): The Christmas Gift](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119081/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-20-the-christmas-gift) by [Stevo](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/73193/stevo)
21. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 21): Color of the Bells](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119091/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-21-color-of-the-bells) by [cap](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57156/cap)
22. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 22): Santa's Sleigh Route](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119107/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-22-santas-sleigh-route) by [TakingNotes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54081/takingnotes)
23. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 23): Christmas Classifieds](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119116/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-23-christmas-classifieds) by [Spencer Fleming](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34617/spencer-fleming)
24. [PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 24): Merry Christmas and a happy New Year!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119121/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-24-merry-christmas-and-a-happy-new-year) by [TakingNotes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54081/takingnotes)