# Puzzling Advent Calendar - 2023

Tags: discussion

<sub>Previous years: [2021](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7272/puzzling-advent-calendar-2021), [2022](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7413/puzzling-advent-calendar-2022)</sub>

---

There will be a Christmas-themed puzzle every day between the 1st and 24th of December, where the accepted answer will be rewarded with a bounty.

To make this work, we need a few users who are willing to prepare nice puzzles for this event. Note that the awarding of bounties is handled separately, so you can join without having to give rep away (although you can optionally choose to award a bounty yourself). To post a puzzle for this event, you should meet the following criteria:

- You have posted at least one question on PSE with a vote score of at least 5.
- The puzzle is Christmas-themed ([seasonal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasonal)).
- The title of the puzzle should be `PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day X): {puzzle title}`.
- A header with a link to this post and the previous/next entries of the calendar (if and when available): `<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2023](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7527). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth {X} reputation.<br><br>[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](link) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](link)</sub><hr>`
- If possible, please post a hint every ~24 hours as long as your puzzle remains unsolved.

Please do not announce your participation in an answer or comment to this post. We will plan the allocations of puzzles in a spreadsheet and coordinate / discuss puzzles in [this dedicated chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149416/pse-advent-calendar-2023).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[<kbd>`14`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/124658/)
[<kbd>`18`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/124727)
[<kbd>`03`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123463)
[<kbd>`06`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123520)
[<kbd>`19`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124738)
[<kbd>`05`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123497)
[<kbd>`13`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123647/)
[<kbd>`23`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/124806/)
[<kbd>`15`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/124680/)
[<kbd>`04`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123481)
[<kbd>`08`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123552)
[<kbd>`20`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/124747)
  
[<kbd>`21`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/124765)
[<kbd>`11`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123596)
[<kbd>`09`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123569)
[<kbd>`02`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123454)
[<kbd>`22`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/124796)
[<kbd>`17`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/124699)
[<kbd>`10`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123585)
[<kbd>`24`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/124826/)
[<kbd>`07`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123528)
[<kbd>`12`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123637)
[<kbd>`01`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123418)
[<kbd>`16`</kbd>](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/124692)

List of all questions posted as part of the PSE Advent Calendar 2023:

1. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 1): Reindeer identification](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123418/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-1-reindeer-identification)
2. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 2): Wall I want for Christmas](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123454/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-2-wall-i-want-for-christmas)
3. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 3): 24 dangerous doors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123463/puzzling-advent-calendar-2023-day-3-24-dangerous-doors)
4. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 4): A few of my favo(u)rite things](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123481/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-4-a-few-of-my-favourite-things)
5. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 5): Twin-brother waiters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123497/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-5-twin-brother-waiters)
6. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 6): It's a beautiful day for a ballgame](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123520/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-6-its-a-beautiful-day-for-a-ballgame)
7. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 7): The Oracle Rambles On and On](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123528/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-7-the-oracle-rambles-on-and-on)
8. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 8): A Quilt for Santa](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123552/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-8-a-quilt-for-santa)
9. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 9): The Peppermint Twist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123569/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-9-the-peppermint-twist)
10. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 10): Captain Christmas](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123585/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-10-captain-christmas)
11. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 11): Divide the cookies and milk](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123596/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-11-divide-the-cookies-and-milk)
12. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 12): A peaceful tree](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123637/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-12-a-peaceful-tree)
13. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 13): Santa likes cards but dislikes dice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123647/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-13-santa-likes-cards-but-dislikes-dice)
14. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 14): Stocking stuffers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124658/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-14-stocking-stuffers)
15. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 15): Finding Father Christmas](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124680/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-15-finding-father-christmas)
16. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 16): Making a list and checking it](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124692/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-16-making-a-list-and-checking-it)
17. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 17): FA-LA-LA-LA-LA LA-LA-LA-LA](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124699/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-17-fa-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la)
18. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 18): A holly jolly Hexologic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124727/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-18-a-holly-jolly-hexologic)
19. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 19): A Christmas Family Union](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124738)
20. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 20): Candles on the tree](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124747)
21. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 21): Oh oh oh](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124765)
22. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 22): The long and the short of it](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124796)
23. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 23): O O O O O O O](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124806/)
24. [PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 24): ... and a Kappa Nu Year!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124826/)

Comment: I like the doors! Great look :) How about putting them in a random order, like on a real Advent calendar?? (And, of course, this being Puzzling, maybe we should use a magic square - albeit with no 25: a central blank?)

Comment: @Stiv Done, I put them in code blocks to make the blank work, which also makes them a bit wider, but it has the nice side effect of showing which puzzles are already available

Comment: That looks great - awesome job! :D